# Is it too late for me to become good at piano?

Tags: piano, beginner

I am 13 and starting to learn piano. I have been asking many people online, who claim to know piano, how long have they been playing. Most, if not all, say that they started between 5-9. I have a dream of becoming a concert pianist one day, decades from now of course. But in general I just want to be pretty good at it, is it too late? Can I not become good since I'm starting late compared to them?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you learning with a teacher?

Comment: Oh hi! Sadly, I am not learning with a teacher since I live in a small town that doesn't have affordable piano teaching. Also, the ones out of town are too expensive for me. I am going to be learning on one of those online courses, I'm still deciding on which one though.

Comment: I’m 47 and taking piano lessons and have gotten close to a skill level I never thought I’d reach. It’s never too late.

Comment: If you work hard towards your dream, there is nothing that you cannot achieve.

Comment: Oh thank you, thank you! I'm really eager to learn and I will work my hardest, I'll try not to overdo it though. I don't want to be burnt out hah.

Comment: I wish I'd started at 13... You may never reach concert level - you really DO need a teacher for that - but youtube videos are an excellent place to start. We're not supposed to recommend in here, so I won't say anything like Pianote. You should get to 'Church level' very quickly.

Comment: Ironically enough, Pete, I might get actually lessons when we move. California is very expensive (the lessons plus gas is too much)  but when we're in Texas I will. I have family over there that can teach me, I just need the internet for my current situation. I do know that I won't get super mega good on my own. Are books a good for me to learn something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is It too late to start learning keyboard again?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12441/is-it-too-late-to-start-learning-keyboard-again)

Comment: You need to define "good". Good enough for Carnegie Hall? Not everyone who starts at 5 years old gets that good. Good enough for the school orchestra? Certainly! How good do you yourself want to be? Whatever, start now and practice every day and see how it goes. But don't give up the day job.

Comment: Related comic : https://xkcd.com/447/

Comment: When I was in school (40-50 years ago), the school band was offered starting in 5th grade. While there are some children who start learning instruments on their own earlier, most waited until around this time, and you could still expect to become good (but not necessarily great) if you devoted yourself enough. It's no different from any other skill.

Comment: @RedSonja Good for me is being able to play in a church or for a school of some sort.

Comment: https://www.beautifulnews.com/i-was-told-i-was-too-old-play-jazz-pianist-challenges-limits-age

Comment: I'm twenty. I started playing violin last year. At this point I sound decent. It's a wonderful thing to play an instrument and I don't think there's such thing as "too late." The point is not to be a Carnegie hall star but the process of practicing, the joy of playing for yourself and other people. It adds spice and texture to regular life.

Comment: If you are passionate about your instrument, it's never too late. There was no possibility for me to start playing saxophone when I was a kid/teenager, and I had only started at the age of 25. At the age of 28 I picked up flute in addition to the saxophone.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How good you will become and how soon will depend on three things -

1. How much time you practice per day. If you practice for an hour a day you will improve almost twice as fast as if you practice for half an hour a day.
2. When you give up playing. If you stop enjoying it or other things in your life become more important then you will either drastically decrease the amount you practice and play or stop altogether. This is what happens to most youngsters.
3. The quality of the tuition you receive. If you try and learn completely online then your progress will be much slower and likely to also stop much sooner.

Why starting very young seems to be important for becoming a soloist is that if you fall in love with a particular instrument at a very young age then that love is more likely to preclude love for anything else than if you start later. Start later and you may already love other pursuits but if your love for your instrument and dedication and hard work matches the early starters for as long then you should achieve similar results.

On the subject of just how much to practice, I particularly like something attributed to the late 19th and early 20th century violin teacher, [Leopold Auer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_Auer), who trained most of the greats of the first half of the 20th century.

> Practice three hours a day if you are any good, four if you are a
> little stupid. If you need more than that, stop. You should find
> another line of work

Three hours a day when you are a complete beginner is obviously far too much. Apart from anything else you are likely to develop overuse injuries, but his advice has a lot of merit for advanced students. A real teacher will help you avoid injury.

The other thing to note about practice is that it must engage the brain to succeed in the long run. You have to think about what you are doing for most of the time you are practising. Mindless repetition is more likely to make you worse than better. Again, a real teacher will be of enormous help here.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I kinda have to learn online since my town doesn't offer much when it comes to music. When there is something it is normally very expensive. But I can also use books, will they help? My schooling is only once a week so I will have free time to practice once an hour. Luckily I know a little when it comes to music practice like how not to just play the things I have achieved. Thank you once again!

Comment: @Fly-GooglyEyes - Tuition once a week combined with practicing an hour per day is close to the ideal mix for a beginner.  You can use books and online resources to complement in-person schooling, to keep yourself challenged and improving.

Comment: Disagree with the amount of practice time equating to how much improvement. It's more what gets put into that time, and how soon the boredom kicks in. Some may be capable of practising fruitfully for hours - others, like me, find 10/15 mins is all we can cope with.

Comment: I've got to agree with Tim here. IMO It takes many months to build up to say an hour. Agree on the 10/15mins, definitely more focused and measurable. You can more easily say or journal what you've done in a smaller time period. And you're more likely to be consistent with a smaller time-frame and stick at it. [Aside, I've done this recently with silent meditation, took 3 months to comfortably stick to over 20 mins]

Answer (score 10):

The accompanist for the choir I sing in just finished his doctorate in piano performance at UT Austin.  (Butler School of Music is a very good school.)  I know a few graduates of this school, and this guy is a cut above all of them.  Perfect technique and control, yet not robotic.

He didn't start piano until he was 16.  I'd guess his age now would be 33-ish.  But he was pretty good 5 years ago when he was working on his masters degree.  And he has played at Carnegie Hall, not as the soloist, but accompanying someone.

Second story:  I started learning pipe organ at age 50.  I'm now 60.  I wouldn't call myself "good", but I can sub for the real organist at church on the Sundays she's gone.

Since you're a little older you'll learn the basics faster.  You'll have no trouble catching up to the guys who started at age 5.

Answer (score 8):

> I am 13...

I stopped reading at that point. Of course it's not too late! Don't limit yourself. Don't let someone else limit you.

> ...I have a dream of becoming a concert pianist one day, decades from now of course. But in general I just want to be pretty good at it...

OK, I continued reading... Now we get to the real issue: what actually is your goal?

"Concert pianist" and "pretty good" aren't interchangeable goals. Adding things like "I have a dream" or "in general I just want" IMO only obscure what you really want. It's important to know what *you* want, because there is a risk of giving up if you don't.

But instead of burdening yourself with questions of what the future holds ask yourself what you are prepared to do *now*! I'm sure you have read about how many hours a day the most serious musician practice. Figure out how much you can commit yourself to practicing. (The fact you are thinking about this at age 13 makes me think you are very self motivated.)

Start to feel out how much time you can practice and how to fit a daily habit into your life. Also, develop a sense for self assessment. Practice where you are weak then move on to something new after you make improvements.

Take time to find good method books and pedagogical (teaching) material. Look for material that covers ergonomics (body mechanics) so you develop good form for the beginning. Also look for classic teaching material - stuff like *Klavierbüchlein für Wilhelm Friedemann Bach* or Clementi's *Introduction to the Art of Playing on the Pianoforte* - or well developed graded material like the [ABRSM syllabus](https://us.abrsm.org/media/62972/piano_syllabus_2019___2020_complete.pdf). There is a lot to choose from. There isn't one best source. The important thing is to use your judgement and don't take any old Youtube tutorial.

A large part of your question is about comparing yourself to others. Ranking musicians and performance grades/competition has always struck me a strange and for the individual it's fraught with disappointment. Being #1 isn't what music is about. Expression and enjoyment are the point. Regarding skill the important comparison to make is you to yourself.

Start now. Don't stop. Play what you like to play.

Comment: My goal, that I think is right for me, is just to have enough skill to play with a whole group of people that is advanced, like at a church or at a school. Of course I want to be at the same level as them. I didn't word it well sorry. I know not to take a Youtube Tutorial, I just need something online for my current situation(it is not YOutube) but in a year or so I'll get actual lessons. I just have issues with comparing myself to others and I though it was too late.

Comment: If the goal is to play with a group of people, the first step is to pick any other instrument than piano. It's the one instrument with most competition and very few groups have room for more than one pianist.

Comment: @ojs Ironically enough, I used to play clarinet. I have some skill in that. And my goal, more specifically, is to play piano in that group since a lot of instruments aren't really my taste. (I am square if you want to say that). So my goal isn't that one-sided lol, I should've been more specific. I might pick more things when I am older though.

Answer (score 5):

I started at the age of six and at the age of nine won a national piano competition in my country - Poland. As a professional pianist and piano teacher I can only say, that it is never too late to start working on yourself. Music and especially piano requires lots of work and time spent on it. But it is never too late to enjoy it, which is the most important.

Comment: Dang, at that young?! I will say that working hard and research is my strength, so that is a good thing for me, I think. May I ask, are books a good source of information for piano? I like to read and I want to know if I can put that skill and, a  lot, into my progress.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. I have a dream of becoming a concert pianist one day, decades from now of course.

> 2. But in general I just want to be pretty good at it,

> 3. is it too late?

It is definitely not too late for 2. I took up guitar at the age of 16. I changed to classical guitar at 18 and managed to get into music college a few years older than the other students. I qualified as a teacher and taught for many years, occasionally giving local concerts. However I was never of concert standard compared to the virtuosi who were out there. In any case I didn't want the lifestyle of always living in hotel rooms in different countries.

With regard to 3. From my own experience I can guarantee that, provided your hands and feet work well enough, and you practise sufficiently, it is not too late to become excellent, not just pretty good.

With regard to 1. History is full of people who have defied the odds. Who are we to say you can't do it? There is also a demand for excellent accompanists to classical singers for example. These require a different skill-set from those performing concertos etc.

There is an old saying, ['It's better to have loved and lost than never to have loved at all'](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/its-better-to-have-loved-and-lost-than-never-to-have-loved-at-all.html)

I think this could be extended to, 'It's better to have tried to become a concert-pianist and only become a very good pianist than never to have tried at all'

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

One advantage you have over 5 or 6 year-olds is that your hands are close to being the size they will be for the rest of your life! That's something younger beginners have to cope with.

Age is, as they say, just a number. More important is your musicality, ability to practise properly, and propensity to make sacrifices, which will happen in the next few years if you want to become really good.

It is quite possible to learn from the internet, with no real teacher, but you'll have to sort the wheat from the chaff. How will you know if a site is good, bad or indifferent?

Having a piano, time and place to practise, and the yearning is all boding well, but having a live teacher will make a huge difference to your progress and understanding. Without, you'll need to set your own goals, and work on whatever at a pace you decide. A (good) teacher will improve all that.

So, no, it's not too late - it's never to late to learn, particularly music, so get on with it NOW !

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not it's "too late" depends on your goals and expectations.

The fact is that in the performing arts one needs to start as early as possible to develop the skills necessary to get into a conservatory by high school or college, in you teenage years.  But this is because one has an expectation of starting their career in their early 20s. This is true in athletics, ballet dancing, etc.

In addition to the above consideration, mastering a musical instrument requires constant practice and attention to your development.  This is a life long pursuit and most musicians get better with age up to a point where age can no longer be ignored.  No matter how much you practice if you life into your 90s your skills will begin to decay.  By how much depends on lifestyle and genetics.  I saw Andre Segovia perform in his 90s and it was not great.  That being said, if you start too, way too, late then entropy will win.

I think 13 is a perfect time to start, you are not too late.  But you have posed a specific goal, that of being a concert pianist.  To accomplish this specific goal would require entering a conservatory at an early age, perhaps by age 16, or at least by college.  Again, this is to meet the expectation of a career as a concert pianist at a reasonable age.  If you really dedicate yourself to practice now, and make good progress this is possible.

On the lighter side, if you just want to enjoy playing and get "good" at it you are definitely NOT TOO LATE.  Most kids don't start until their early teens and many become virtuosos.  I can only cite anecdotal cases.  For example, a good friend of mine didn't start music lessons on any instrument until age 16 and became an exceptional percussionist and guitarist.  I worked with him in several bands in college.  He is not a professional musician, working as a manager in some tech industry but he is good enough to compete with classically trained musicians for spots in orchestras, etc.  Myself, I started on violin at age 5, eventually moving to guitar at 8, then classical bass in high school, at 16.  I do work as a musician but in college changed majors to physics.  I have no doubt that starting early gave me an advantage in terms of picking up new things easily (drums, horns, etc), but some friends of mine who started lessons late in high school rapidly surpassed me by sheer dedication.

You are very young and can progress quite a bit before college if you start now.  If you are serious about making a life long hobby or even a career as a musician I would start lessons now, and get involved in any programs your school or community has for music.  This will connect you to the music education community and will provide support for developing in the right direction, getting the skills needed to do what is expected.  When I was in high school we were required to compete in all state music competitions as part of our grade, sort of like athletes competing at matches, etc.  This is the kind of experience that will prepare you for entering a conservatory and a music program later in life.

Comment: I can't really join anything at the moment, Covid and my school never offered anything that involved piano. Just, brass, wind, some string, and percussion instruments. My community is low income and is very small so that is a big no. I  have to learn on my own for now ( when I move in a year that will change).

Answer (score 1):

*At worst*, you'll be a little "behind" your peers who started at a younger age, but this really only means that you won't be performing in big-name stuff until your late 20s or early 30s. Realistically, you're young enough that you should have no trouble "catching up" if you put in the time.

13 is a great age to begin learning piano. And since you're just starting and are still plenty young, be open to other avenues for the skill. Maybe you'll find something else that fits you even better than your current dream of being a concert pianist.

You will go as far as you are willing to take it seriously and practice the amount necessary to achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0):

Always do what you want anyway, as you might not know what it really is. You might end up somewhere you'd never expect to be and still be perfectly happy with it. Happiness is the road.

Answer (score -4):

You can certainly become good starting at age 13.
It would be difficult to become great.

Adults have an ability to learn the piano in less time  than kids do but other factors limit how well they can end up becoming which has more to do with their brain and dexterity but mostly the brain.   And  the brain has more to do with music in general than piano per se.  Sort of like it is easier to learn a second language when you are young than to do it when you are grown up.